# Remove values after decimal in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code which gives me result: 4.00 USD

```
<?php echo $number->currency($auction['Product']['rrp'], $appConfigurations['currency']); ?>
```

I want to remove decimal. Result should be 4USD,  I have tried php function round, but dosn't work. I am using cakephp framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the options

As indicated in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/number.html#NumberHelper::currency) - you can specify the decimal places to use via the options array:

> places    Number of decimal places to use. ie. 2

```
echo $number->currency(
    $auction['Product']['rrp'], 
    $appConfigurations['currency'],
    array('places' => 0)
);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the amount has decimals and you set ['places' => 0], the  output will be rounded up. i.e. $9.50 will output $10.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code also :

```
 Rs. <?php $offerPrice = $this->Number->currency($relatedProduct['StoreProduct']['offer_price'],"") ; 
         echo substr($offerPrice,0, strpos($offerPrice,"."))  ?> 

//input =  3,175.00 
//output =  3,175
```